# Сбивается время в Win7 ровно на 3 часа. Часовой пояс сохраняется

Tags: windows-7, время

**Предыстория:**

На 240-гигабайтном SSD-накопителе десктопа стояли лицензионная 7-я Винда (около 140 Гб) и Ubuntu 14.04. Решил подключить второй монитор, чтобы удобнее было учиться. Подключал, естественно, при выключенном системном блоке.

В результате Виндоус перестала запускаться совсем (уходила в ребут после одного бегунка при загрузке), а Убунту никаких проблем не показала - стала работать на 2 монитора, как хотелось.

Поскольку восстановить Виндоус не удалось никакими средствами (руки вроде бы растут откуда надо, кое-что умею), поставил ту же самую систему заново, предварительно обновив Убунту до 16.04. Еще при этом заменил батарейку на материнской плате на новую.

**Сама проблема:**

Все бы ничего, но за прошедший месяц заметил неприятную мелочь - после нескольких дней работы у Виндоус слетает время ровно на 3 часа, при этом часовой пояс сохраняется. Т.е. сейчас у меня по Киеву должно быть 19:43, а Виндоус показывает 16:43.

Поймать момент, когда это происходит - не удавалось пока.

Кто что может подсказать?

Comment: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F_windows_%D0%B8_ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Ubuntu в терминале прописать `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`, и тогда на Windows 7 время сбиваться не будет.
По умолчанию Ubuntu при загрузке устанавливает таймер BIOS в UTC 0 (Coordinated Universal Time - Координированное Универсальное Время). А Windows загрузившись воспринимает это время как локальное и показывает его как ни в чем не бывало

Comment: А как это связано? Система меняет время в BIOS, а Windows берет время из BIOS?

Comment: По умолчанию Ubuntu при загрузке устанавливает таймер BIOS в UTC 0 (Coordinated Universal Time - Координированное Универсальное Время). А Windows загрузившись воспринимает это время как локальное и показывает его как ни в чем не бывало.

Comment: Т.е., получается, время в Виндоус слетает после того, как я на Убунте побывал? Сейчас проверю.

Comment: Действительно, после перезагрузки с Убунты в Виндоус сразу же устанавливается время на три часа меньшее, чем в часовом поясе. При этом в самой Убунте при загрузке сначала показывается время на 3 часа большее, чем в часовом поясе, а затем, через несколько десятков секунд идет синхронизация с интернетом и время становится правильным...

Comment: @tirael8 добавте ваш комментарий в ответ